# How to make website responsively?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

how to do responsive design in a web page

Comment: YOu will need to use bootstrap css .. http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap or http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: @rajeev *"could"* is far better than *"need"*. Specially when talking about bootstrap and w3schools as a learning resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a responsive design.

W3schools is a good starting point.

Check out their site on [HTML Responsive Web Design](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp)

You can also use Responsive Frameworks that will help you easily write responsive code. Examples include Bootstrap (by Twitter) and W3.CSS (by W3Schools)

W3Schools also has a site on that: [Responsive Web Design - Frameworks](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_frameworks.asp)

Comment: I have did that things,but...my header buttons(films,songs,about us) did not allow it,i want to do as when I resize header items its come to one drop down list